# Why after create elements with jquery they'r not visible in Chrome

Tags: jquery, dom, google-chrome

I am creating elements with jQuery in a simple way.

So it should work after document ready, and it works fine with IE, but not with Chrome, Firefox or Safari.
They are created, but are not visible!

In chrome for example, when I include an alert after document ready, after click ok, elements become visible, or when I open "inspect elemnt" elements become visible too.

Any one knows what is the problem?

```
var radio_span = $('<span></span>')
 .addClass('jqTransformRadioWrapper')
 .attr('id', spanRadio_id) (...etc)
```

Comment: Please create a http://jsfiddle.net/ demo to exemplify your problem. The code snippet alone is not sufficient to follow or solve your problem. For example, the code you posted does not show how you add the new element to the DOM tree. Without providing more information, it is impossible to help you.

Answer (score 1):

```
var radio_span = $('<span></span>')
 .addClass('jqTransformRadioWrapper')
 .attr('id', spanRadio_id) (...etc)
```

What this does is put your element in the radio_span variable, to see the element you will have to somehow insert it into the document with append, prepend, html or any other method that does this, like so:

```
radio_span.appendTo('body');
```

http://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/zKWxp/4/

I see now that your writing that elements become visible when opening inspect element or adding an alert, wich sound very strange, and you will probably have to do what Felix is saying, add more code!

Comment: Thank you for answering, but of course i append it, or it would not work in any browser. And as i say it works in all browsers, but not right after opening with chrome, etc. Any way i change the order of elements and some how it worked...perhaps it was kind of a delay...realy don't know.

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't it be this:

```
var radio_span = $('#spanid');
 radio_span.addClass('jqTransformRadioWrapper');
```

Comment: No, jQuery allows method chaining.

Answer (score 0):

try to wrap your code in:

```
$(function() { ... });
```

If this doesn't work then try to wrap it into:

```
$(window).load(function () { ...  });
```